# Forms sometimes open as tabbed documents and sometimes not

Tags: ms-access

I am working in Access 365 and am struggling with forms that sometimes launch as pop-ups and sometimes launch as tabbed documents.

My database Options-->Datasheet-->Document Window Options are set to Tabbed Documents and checked for Display Document Tabs.

My form Properties are set to Popup = No and Modal = No.

I'm going around in circles trying to figure out a pattern as to why sometimes the same form will open as a tab but other times open as a pop-up.

Here is one example:  I have a navigation form that shows a list of customers, and double-clicking on the customer name fires off a simple macro that does the following:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCustomerInfo", _
WhereCondition:="[ID] = " & Me.[ID], _
DataMode:=acFormEdit, _
WindowMode:=acDialog
```

However, when I launch the CustomerInfo form from the navigation form, it is opening as a pop-up.

Can anyone help provide some insight? Is there another setting that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please double check `Popup` property.

Comment: `WindowMode:=acDialog` opens a popup form.

Comment: (...face palm...)  Thanks @Andre for your reply about WindowMode. The answer was there right in front of me the whole time.